# Elastix eFax Unicode support

Tags: linux, fax, elastix

We are using Elastix as an eFax system, the issue is that when trying to send Arabic text it appeas as "????".

The issue appears to be in converting the text to postscript, Elastix uses HylaFax as virtual Fax and Hylafax uses:

```
/usr/sbin/textfmt   -B -f Courier-Bold -Ml=0.4in -p11
```

to convert the text to postscrit,

The question is that is it possible to support arabic characters in postscript ??
i have checked this function in linux:

```
groff  -Tps  file  >file.ps
```

it also does not support,

```
warning: can't find special character `u0642'
```

Any idea ....

Answer (score 1):

The best way of doing this is not letting hylafax do any conversion. textfmt can only do ascii, so any other characters are bound to break. A better option is to feed hylafax PDF files you generate yourself.

A possible way of doing this is to use HTML instead of text files, and using something like [wkhtmltopdf](http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/) to convert these to PDF.

Comment: I have been checking to do the conversion to pdf on the linux, non seems promising. do you know of any tool to do. my last try was with u2ps -->> ps2pdf  which did not work :)

Comment: I mentioned one in my answer. We send about 500000 faxes per day using that :)

Comment: Thanks, my mistake i did not notice that it's a shell command, unfortunately Arabic characters are not supported in this tool, the characters translated to separated junk blocks.